# Flutter auto_route | Pass data to outer router in nested navigation

Tags: flutter, nested, navigation, state-management

I am using Flutter *auto_route* for my nested navigation, where I would like to pass data (A dynamic string for the `AppBar`-title and a `Widget` for the floatingActionButton) from a nested route to an outer route (two levels up from the according to the route tree).

The navigation (tree) has the following structure:

[image: Structure of nested navigation]

```dart
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(
      page: MainNavigationView,
      children: [
        AutoRoute(
          path: 'manage',
          page: EmptyRouterPage,
          name: 'ManageRouter',
          children: [
            AutoRoute(
              path: 'object',
              page: ObjectView,
              initial: true,
            ),
            AutoRoute(
              path: 'detail',
              page: ObjectDetailView,
            ),
          ]
        )
      ]
    )
  ]
)
```

My Page uses nested navigation, where `MainNavigationView` represents the `Scaffold` which holds an `AppBar` and `SpeedDial` as `floatingActionButton` of the `Scaffold`:

```dart
class MainNavigationView extends StatefulWidget {
...
}

class _MainNavigationViewState extends State<MainNavigationView> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return AutoTabsRouter(
      routes: [
        const ManageRouter(),
        ...
      ],
      builder: (context, child, __) {
        final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldkey,
          appBar: AppBar(...), //Title needs to be set dynamically
          body: child,
          floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
            ... //This needs to be set dynamically
          ),
          ...
        );
      },
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

Inside the route `ManageRouter`, I can navigate from `ObjectView` to `ObjectDetailView`. From both views, I need to pass a dynamic string for the AppBar and the necessary Objects for the `floatingActionButton`.

The only solution I came up with was a `Provider`, for the `MainNavigationView` which would allow me the send the data in a decoupled manner. But it seems like overkill, for something this general.

**UPDATE:**

I have looked into several other solutions. None of them had a scenario where there was a scaffold in the parent and the nested router was passing values to the parent `Scaffold`. What I have seen in other examples of other router packages (such as `go_router`) was a `Scaffold` in the `MainNavigationView` with a `bottomNavigationBar` property set and no `appBar` or `floatingBottons` property set. And the nested content (`Object`/`ObjectDetail` via `ManageRouter`) has its own `Scaffold` with properties set for `appBar` and `bottomNavigationBar`.

I have tried solving it with the state management solutions such as `Provider` but besides problems with triggering a `notifyListeners()`-action while building (because I placed the `notifyListeners()` action inside the build-method of the nested content) I had a problem regarding the stack management. Handling that logic, with the side effects of a bottomNavigationBar, which has its own stack, I figured that it is an architectural problem.

I still thank you alls for your effort and interest!

Comment: do you just want to pass data from one page to another? you can use getx, which has an argument option to pass data.

Answer (score 0):

I think AutoRouter package doesn't have any functionality to pass a parameter between Nested routes. Your situation can be solved much easier!

**AutoTabsRouter** have field named activeIndex.
And this field will updates in AutoTabsRouter builder method when you select an page from your MainNavigationView children.

I use this in my applications to display the selected page icon in the bottomNavigationBar and selected page title in appBar.

Solution for your situation:

```dart
class MainNavigationView extends StatefulWidget {
...
}

class _MainNavigationViewState extends State<MainNavigationView> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return AutoTabsRouter(
      routes: [
        const ManageRouter(),
        ...
      ],
      builder: (context, child, __) {
        final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldkey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: tabsRouter.activeIndex == 1? 'ObjectViewTitle' : 'ObjectDetailViewTitle'
          ), //Title needs to be set dynamically
          body: child,
          floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
            child: tabsRouter.activeIndex == 1? ObjectViewFab() : ObjectDetailViewFab() 
          ),
          ...
        );
      },
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is, that the title and `floatingActionButton`-object are static. But I don't know which title `ObjectDetail` will have until I have a selected an object. Therefore the data in the `AppBar`-title and floatingActionButton` needs to be in the context of the specific `ObjectDetail`-object.

Comment: In this case, use Provider / Bloc / Controller or another state machine... This is not a bad solution in your situation.